# Embed google map from shared url

Tags: google-maps

If I have an string url like `https://goo.gl/maps/h3maMVM6JHJ2`

How can I get the url `https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wal+Mart/@1.0124826,102.7074445,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31d6da283960bf79:0xff2a6dc939314ae0!8m2!3d1.0124826!4d102.7096332`
 using **javascript**

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the link: https://goo.gl/maps/h3maMVM6JHJ2

resolves to:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/place/Wal+Mart/@1.0124826,102.7074445,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x31d6da283960bf79:0xff2a6dc939314ae0!8m2!3d1.0124826!4d102.7096332
```

2. click on the share icon:

[image: share icon]

3. click on "Embed Map":

[image: embed map]

4. click on "COPY HTML"

[image: copy HTML]

You will get an `<iframe>` with the `src=` attribute you need:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3989.1953868324035!2d102.70744451475375!3d1.0124825992614412!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31d6da283960bf79%3A0xff2a6dc939314ae0!2sWal+Mart!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1545288648700" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3989.1953868324035!2d102.70744451475375!3d1.0124825992614412!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x31d6da283960bf79%3A0xff2a6dc939314ae0!2sWal+Mart!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1545288648700" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I mean how can I get the src attribute with javascript code, sorry I don't mention it in the question

Comment: Not possible (at present), you at least need the non-minimized link.